# How to grab current date data - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-datetime

Below is my code that is grabbing data and converting the data into a CSV file (this is working). I am trying to only focus on the data that is returned for the current date.

Could someone show me how this is done please, DTDT is the date.

Currently the CSV is filled with data from random dates that I do not want.

My Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST*"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

For example, I want the data only return and shown in the CVS for today date.

Comment: Does the elasticsearch server let you query on dates, or is that not an index that is available?

Comment: I am not sure if it allowed me but there is a index called _source and a doc type called DTDT.

Comment: `_source` is not an index, I don't think. If there is a date index, you can add that to the query to limit results. Leave the filtering on date to the elasticsearch server if possible, that would be much more efficient all round.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that please?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry. I'd have to go look up the elasticsearch documuntation, it's been a while since I worked with their API. You'll have to figure out first what indices there are configured.